# scroll event not fired for apple-mobile-web-app-capable during deceleration

Tags: jquery, html, ios, scroll, safari

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`

I have an event that fires on scroll to change the title of the current month on my calendar web app. This works perfectly in safari when I load the page but after adding this meta tag and saving the app to my homescreen the event stoped firing as the scroll is decelerating. As long as my finger is on the screen it is able to change the title but the scroll event will no longer fire during the deceleration of the momentum scroll.

I understand that in the first releases of ios javascript was not fired during the scroll event but this was fixed in ios 8. Why would enabling `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` cause a regression in this behaviour?

```
$(".dates_container_m").on( 'scroll', function(){

  //change the title if scroll into next month

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know more info here:

Follow this link for more info: [click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

Try this like this code:

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", OnScrollStart, false);
document.addEventListener("scroll", OnScroll, false);

function OnScrollStart() {
    //start of scroll event for iOS
}

function OnScroll() {
    //end of scroll event for iOS
    //and
    //start/end of scroll event for other browsers
}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not change it. My problem is it behaves differently when the meta tag is added. I want to display the page in full screen but would rather have the scroll event firing.